# How do I get traps in Lihzahrd Temple?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I want to get traps like "Super Dart Trap", "Spiky Ball Trap", but I cannot break them by Drax.
In order to get them, do I need Picksaw? Or I can get them by other ways?

Comment: I can't speak English well, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least 210% pickaxe power is required to mine the traps found in the Jungle Temple, so you need a Picksaw or better pickaxe.